# jQuery delay fadeIn taking longer than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to fade out a CSS3 preloader with jQuery. I have been trying to stop the animation (which is a box rotating), and then fade in a letter inside the box then, have them both fade out, the letter fading out a little later than the box. I have had the problem where the letter fades in way later than I want it to and when it comes on if fades out really fast. Here is the code:

```js
 //<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
$('.loader-inner').css({'-webkit-animation': 'none'});
$('.loader').delay(100).css({'-webkit-animation': 'none'}); // will first fade out the loading animation
$('.letter').delay(100).fadeIn('slow'); 
$('.preloader').delay(2050).fadeOut('slow');// will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
$('.letter').delay(2060).fadeOut(900);
$('body').delay(2060).css({'overflow':'visible'});
  });
 //]]>
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  }
.preloader {
 position: fixed;
 

 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 99999;
 background-color: #2f2f2f;
}

.loader {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 5px solid #d5b317;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
  z-index: -10;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -29px
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5b317;
  -webkit-animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
  z-index: -10;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Adobe Gurmukhi';
    src: url(/fonts/AdobeGurmukhi-Regular.ttf);
}

.letter {
 display:hidden;
 color: #f7d11e;
 font-family: 'Adobe Gurmukhi';
 font-size: 70px;
 position:absolute;  
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -17px;
 margin-left: -19px;
 z-index: -9;

}
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  
  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
<!--preloader-->
 <div class="preloader">
   <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
     </div>
    <span><p class="letter">ਅ</p></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index of `.preloader` (99999) is higher than that of `.letter` (-9). That delay you are experiencing is the delay until `.preloader` fades out and thus reveals `.letter`. As a quick fix I made the z-index of `.letter` higher than that of `.preloader` and that delay is gone.

```js
 //<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
$('.loader-inner').css({'-webkit-animation': 'none'});
$('.loader').delay(100).css({'-webkit-animation': 'none'}); // will first fade out the loading animation
$('.letter').delay(100).fadeIn('slow'); 
$('.preloader').delay(2050).fadeOut('slow');// will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
$('.letter').delay(2060).fadeOut(900);
$('body').delay(2060).css({'overflow':'visible'});
  });
 //]]>
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  }
.preloader {
 position: fixed;
 

 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 99999;
 background-color: #2f2f2f;
}

.loader {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 5px solid #d5b317;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-animation: loader 2s infinite ease;
  z-index: -10;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -29px
}

.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d5b317;
  -webkit-animation: loader-inner 2s infinite ease-in;
  z-index: -10;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Adobe Gurmukhi';
    src: url(/fonts/AdobeGurmukhi-Regular.ttf);
}

.letter {
 display:hidden;
 color: #f7d11e;
 font-family: 'Adobe Gurmukhi';
 font-size: 70px;
 position:absolute;  
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -17px;
 margin-left: -19px;
 z-index: 999999;

}
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  25% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader-inner {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  
  25% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  
  50% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  75% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
<!--preloader-->
 <div class="preloader">
   <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
     </div>
    <span><p class="letter">ਅ</p></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is first you use delay that means you want to call fadeOut after some delay and you given the delay time 2 sec and its working correctly as expected.

Its started fading out after 2 sec.

I think its working as expected if you want to fade it out little soon then you have to reduce the delay time of remove delay.

Hope this may help you.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try the callback function

```
   $('.letter').delay(100).fadeIn('slow', function(){ 
   // function called after fade in finished
    setTimeout(function(){
          $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
          $('.letter').fadeOut(900);
          $('body').css({'overflow':'visible'});
       }, 2600);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this, both will fadeOut at same time.

```
    // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    $('.letter').delay(2060).fadeOut('fast');
```